# Add links to a port channel group without downtime

Tags: spanning-tree, trunk, etherchannel, port-channel

There are two trunk links with the same configuration connecting two switches. Currently they are independent links and one is blocked with spanning-tree. I would like to convert these to a single port channel without any down time. Is this possible? What is the best procedure for doing so?

These are Cisco, but I think the concept would apply to any switches that support the same function.

What I've come up with so far:

1. Shutdown the STP blocked interface, on the core side
2. Add both interfaces on the down connection to the channel group
3. No shutdown the interface that was shut down in step 1 (STP will block again)
4. Shutdown the interface with STP forwarding active (STP will start forwarding on the port channel)
5. Add the interfaces on the down connection to the channel group
6. No shutdown the interface that was shutdown in step 4

The problem is that step 4 here creates about 1 second of outage. Is there a way to do this without any outage?

Comment: You will lose some frames, no matter what you do (STP will need to converge), and if you do it incorrectly, you can end up with err-disabled interfaces that you must shut down then restart, anyway.. The safest thing to do is shut down both physical interfaces on both switches, add the physical interfaces to the channel group on each switch, and then bring up the physical interfaces on both switches.

Comment: Which version of spanning-tree are you using (or better yet provide the output of `show spanning-tree summary`)?

Comment: rapid-pvst
Switch is in rapid-pvst mode
Root bridge for: none
Extended system ID           is enabled
Portfast Default             is disabled
PortFast BPDU Guard Default  is enabled
Portfast BPDU Filter Default is disabled
Loopguard Default            is disabled
EtherChannel misconfig guard is enabled
UplinkFast                   is disabled
Stack port is StackPort2
BackboneFast                 is disabled
Configured Pathcost method used is short

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

While the STP handover in step 4 or step 3 is usually faster than 1 second there's always a gap. Make sure you're using RSTP, MSTP or RPVST though. The original and largely obsolete STP is slow on convergence.

One tiny thing *might* reduce the gap a little further: before step 3, decrease the trunk's STP priority value below that of the yet active port. This will already initiate the handover in step 3, so it doesn't need to be a shutdown reaction but a more 'flowing' process.

As this seems to be very delicate connection I'd stage the exact process in a lab before doing it in production.